# NodeInvocationException: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working with Asp.Net Core and Angular 4 as front end.

I am calling ProjectRoleService as follows

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectRoleService {   
    _serverURL: string;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this._serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/api";
    }
    getMenuDetails(roleName: string) {
        let _url = this._serverURL + "/Menu/GetMenuDetails?roleName=" + roleName;

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._http.get(_url)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    reject(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
                })
                .subscribe((data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

I have configured localhost URL as `http://localhost:8080/` and the serverURL as `this._serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/api";`

The `MenuController` class is as follows

```
public class MenuController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>  
        /// Get Menu Details by logged in user role  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <param name="email ID"></param>  
        /// <returns></returns>  
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetMenuDetails(string roleName)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = null;

            try
            {
                httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(new Menu().GetMenuDetails(roleName));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(ex.Message),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Warning"
                });
            }
            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
    }
```

With this I am getting error as below on running from IISExpress. I have enabled only Anonymous for this in Project settings

```
    NodeInvocationException: Unexpected end of JSON input
    SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.module.exports.Body.json (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:71887:25)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:19325:96)
    at CatchSubscriber.module.exports.CatchSubscriber.error (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:91048:31)
    at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber._error (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10724:26)
    at MapSubscriber.module.exports.Subscriber.error (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10698:18)
    at ZoneTask.onComplete [as callback]    (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:4454:30)
    at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85819:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:14821:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (E:\AngularProject\NodeUI\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:85818:36)
```

This happens when I try to run the Project.

1. I suspect the problem is with calling Server URL
2. Is my res.json() good enough?

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Unexpected end of JSON input" indicates that there's some malformed JSON coming through. You should look at your server response and make sure it's actually JSON.

Comment: your response when theres an exception theres no JSON in there.

Comment: `.json()` also returns a promise.

Comment: How can I check whether it is returning json data or not?

Comment: Is there any condition to check the content type?

Comment: Is this the correct URL - `http://localhost:8080/api/menu/getmenudetails?roleName=Admin`